# If-statement never reaches else branch - "if (x = y)"

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this weird problem:

Below is a JavaScript function

```
function calculateSum()
 {
   var e2 = document.getElementById('hotel_names');
   var selValue2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;

   if (selValue2='1')
   {
   alert("helloworld");
   }
   else
   {
   alert("byeworld");
   }
//function closes
 }
```

It captures the option value of an HTML element selection and show the appropriate message...or it should be. The thing is it always shows 1 no matter the selection.

On the other hand the following works.

```
function calculateSum()
     {
       var e2 = document.getElementById('hotel_names');
       var selValue2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;

       alert(selValue2);
     }
```

The second function shows the correct number each time you select an option from the selection. 
Any ideas why the first one does not work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conditional statements use double equals sign called an equality operator -

```
  if (selValue2 == '1'){
    ...
  }
```

By using only one what you are essentially doing is assigning a value to the variable. This is called an assignment operator.

```
selValue2 = '1'
```

Comment: might be worth noting that some people adopt a pattern of comparing equality in reverse to avoid making this mistake with a typo, e.g. `if ('1' == selValue2)`

Comment: @num -that's called yoda conditions :P

Comment: @num - I learnt it from a ([now deleted post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307)) - http://i.imgur.com/Ec4pV.png

Comment: @pan - happens to the best of us :) Sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes :)

Comment: @lix looks like atwood reblogged the top 30 answers from that post [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)

Comment: @num - awesome! Now I can link there for <10Kers :-P hehe.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need an equality operator. You're using an assignment operator. Equality is

```
selValue2 == '1'
```

assignment is

```
selValue2 = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small point to add to the other answers. I'd recommend using `===` instead of `==` for comparisons.

It checks both the value and the type of the parameters being compared and is often quicker.