# Javascript Random Number with Nested If statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

I have some Javascript that selects a random number between 1 and 10, and then loads one of two images into `img.src =` based on whether the random number chosen was above 5.

This is my code:

```
if ((Math.random() * 10) + 1 > 5) {
    img.src = '1.jpg';
} else {
    img.src = '2.jpg';
}
```

This works perfectly for 2 images, however I now want it to choose from 4 images.

I tried doing a nested if statement with the above code but I realised I was running multiple instances of Math.random, which defeated the purpose.

So then I tried to define a variable at the start using Math.random, and then wrote a nested If statement as follows:

```
var picnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

if (picnumber = 1){
  img.src = '1.jpg';
} else {
  if (picnumber = 2){
    img.src = '2.jpg';
  } 
  else {
  if (picnumber = 3){
    img.src = '3.jpg';
  }
  else {
    img.src = '4.jpg';
  }
}}
```

I’ve run this code over 20 times and it keeps loading the same image, image `“1.jpg”`. I think I’m doing something very basic wrong here, how can I ensure that the `var picnumber` will get assigned a random number (either 1, 2, 3 or 4), and that the correct image will be attached to `img.src`? (I want each image to have a 25% chance of being chosen).
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: `var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); img.src = num + ".jpg";`. Keep the parts separate; a lookup or if can be applied trivially as needed. In any case the "problem" has nothing to do with random but has to do with `=` (assignment) vs `==` (equality compare).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369591/if-statement-does-not-work-as-intented-javascript

Answer (score 4):

You're using the assign operator `(=)` instead of the comparison operator `(==)`. Also, you can use the `elseif` and with that way you don't need to put a new if inside the else statement:

```
var picnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

if (picnumber == 1){
  img.src = '1.jpg';
} else if (picnumber == 2) {
    img.src = '2.jpg';
} else if (picnumber == 3) {
    img.src = '3.jpg';
} else {
    img.src = '4.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks @alejandro-bar :) that makes sense! Quick question, if I wanted to expand the number of pictures to say, 200, would this method result in a slow loading time? Or would the application only load one picture (the one that gets selected randomly?)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend putting the pictures in an array.

You could then grab a random picture like this:

```
var pics= ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg'],
    picnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * pics.length));

img.src= pics[picnumber];
```

Comment: Thanks @rick-hitchcock If I expanded the number of pictures to 200 would putting them in an array like this make the application load slower than it would with only a few images? I'm wondering if the Javascript actually checks/pulls all possible images before one is chosen, or if the loading/initiation speed will be the same no matter how many pictures are in the array?

Comment: It would probably be faster to use the array method, because it could index directly into it without trying each `if` test until it found the current `picnumber`.

Comment: It would also save you a bunch of typing! : )

Comment: Note that only the image selected randomly will actually be downloaded, whether you use the array method or the `if` method.

Comment: ah awesome :) thanks. I was wondering would this method: ``var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1); img.src = num + ".jpg";`` be even faster than an array?

Comment: Absolutely.  The array method works well if you have various filenames, but if they're really named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, etc. (with no gaps), then the `num+'.jpg'` method works great.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var picnumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

if (picnumber == 1) {
  img.src = '1.jpg';
} else {
  if (picnumber == 2) {
    img.src = '2.jpg';
  } else {
    if (picnumber == 3) {
      img.src = '3.jpg';
    } else {
      img.src = '4.jpg';
    }
  }
}
```